# Как исправить ошибку в andrax?

Tags: kali-linux

Скачал andrax, полный рут есть, но куда не зайду, в терминале выбивает ошибку

```
chroot: can't execute '/bin/su': no such file or directory
```

Может нужно еще что-то поставить?

Answer (score 1):

1. ROOT with SuperSU
   Если у вас не SuperSU, возможны ошибки. ( у автора поста завелось и с MagiskSU)
   Стандартные root права не подойдут!
2. 7.0GB свободного места на телефоне
   Это достаточно для комфортной работы с Andrax
3. Unlocked Kernel (разблокированное ядро, загрузчик)
   Если у вас samsung устройства, то возможны некоторые ограничения, способные помешать нормальной работе Andrax.
   В этом случае желательно поменять ядро или использовать другие прошивки вроде LineageOS.
4. Android 5.0 или выше.

Andrax портативен на большинстве устройств, использующих android 5.0 и выше.
Andrax автоматически скачивает, устанавливает и настраивает окружение.
Необходимо выдать root права в обязательном порядке!

Ручная установка Официальные проверенные 2 гайда! Требуется 7GB+ Рекомендуется использовать русский мод Andrax! Для ручной установки вам необходимо открыть интерфейс ANDRAX на главном экране, выбрать вкладку «Дополнительно» в меню и нажать «Ручная утсановка», откроется новое окно в браузере по умолчанию и будет загружен файл andrax core.tar.xz.

Метод #1 Для его установки вы можете использовать графический файловый менеджер, такой как « Solid explorer » или любой другой с рут. Просто распакуйте ядро в " /data/data/com.thecrackertechnology.andrax/ANDRAX/ "

Метод #2 Откройте любой терминал(Не Termux), предоставьте рут доступ( Должен быть MagiskSu 15+ или Super Su) И пишем команду: su -c busybox tar -xvJf ПУТЬ К АРХИВУ -C /data/data/com.thecrackertechnology.andrax/ANDRAX/

Ждём завершения!

Comment: текст второго из ваших ответов лучше было добавить прямо к этом ответу, нажав [edit]

Comment: ok - aleksandr barakin